# C++ multiple inheritance and cross delegation with void*?

Tags: c++, void-pointers

```
class Base1
{
public:
    virtual ~Base1(){}

    virtual void whatever()
    {
        cout << "whatever" << endl;
    }
};

class Base2
{
public:
    virtual ~Base2(){}

    virtual void aFunc(int i) = 0;
};

class A : public Base1, public Base2
{
public:
    A()
    {}
    ~A()
    {}

    virtual void aFunc(int i) final
    {
        cout << "func" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    void* a;
    a = new A();

    (static_cast<Base2*>(a))->aFunc(0);

    Base2* ptr = static_cast<Base2*>(a);
    ptr->aFunc(0);

    return 0;
}
```

This example prints out "whatever" instead of "func", if I change the line with void* to A* than it prints out "func". Is this a known behavior? I would expect that's the case just don't know why.

Comment: You've got undefined behaviour.

Comment: Void pointers. Just say no!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a known behavior?

Yes. Behaviour is well-defined if you convert to `void*` and then back to the same type. It's undefined if you convert back to a different type.

> I would expect that's the case just don't know why.

There's no guarantee that a base sub-object has the same address as the complete object; in fact, if there's more than one non-empty base class, then at least one sub-object will have to be at a different address. So a valid conversion from `A*` to `Base2*` probably needs to adjust the value of the pointer, not just reinterpret it as a different type. Conversion to `void*` and back can't make that adjustment.